# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly xampp 3.2.4

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When I open XAMPP (xampp v3.2.4 in windows 10) and click start MySQL button and it gives me an error. I had started it just before, but now it isn't working.

error:

```
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:50:26 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

so, I check log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 51764883; transaction id 105083
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-08-01 12:50:25 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

how do fix this error?

Comment: check if there is alreadys a server, the log shows a normnal start

Comment: @nbk: Sure, server worked without any problem.

Comment: good, you have a running server and then try to start  a new one on the same port?

Comment: @nbk: please see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed using [this](https://www.progschools.com/database/mysql/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/) article:

**Rename the “data” folder**

- Rename the “data” folder to “data-oldfiles”.
- This is very important to rename the data directory to any new directory name.

**Create a new “data” folder**

- Create a new folder and give the folder name as “data“
- To solve the problem we need to create a new “data” directory in the mysql database.

**Copy content from “backup” folder**

- Go to the “backup” folder and copy all files.
- Paste the files from backup folder to data folder
- Now start the MySQL database from XAMPP.
- Now, your MySQL database will start properly without showing any error.

**Transfer all MySQL projects Database, Data file & Log files**

- If you have many database which was used for various projects, then you have to transfer all database from “data-oldfiles” folder to “data” folder.
- Copy all databases from the data-old files and paste to the data folder.
- Now you have to copy the data file “ibdata1” & all log files “ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 ” from data-old files folder to the data folder. If you have many id_logiles then copied all of them.

Answer (score -1):

you can end task mysqld.exe or mysqld on task manager. Then run again MySql. It will work. (On Off Engineering).

Comment: Please share more details. How should any database access work if the service is not running?

Comment: I edited my answer for you.

Comment: Please share more details. Why exactly are you thinking tha restarting the server helps? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer